# Android. Error Invalid capture present 4 for AudioAttributes in 6.0

Tags: android, audiorecord

Hello friends I am working on a Incoming call recorder. Audio recording successfully in below version(I have tried in samsung galaxy s3)but when I try it in 6.0 version it gives me error **E/AudioAttributes: Invalid capture preset 4 for AudioAttributes.**

I have search a lot but didn't find the exact answer.Is there is a bug in android which is giving me error when i used to record the AudioSource.Voice_call.

Thanks in advance .**Please i am stuck if there is any solution to record incoming call in 6.0 Please let me know any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615189/call-recording-with-opensl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time I got the answer. This is due to manufacture issue.In many countries call recording is banned.So manufactures don't allow to record uplink and downlink. There is a way you can open the mic and record it.It's the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ndk. Here are examples of the functions that need to be done.

Load libmedia.so and libutils.so

```
int load(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    void *handleLibMedia;
    void *handleLibUtils;
    int result = -1;
    lspr func = NULL;

    pthread_t newthread = (pthread_t) thiz;

    handleLibMedia = dlopen("libmedia.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (handleLibMedia != NULL) {
        func = dlsym(handleLibMedia, "_ZN7android11AudioSystem13setParametersEiRKNS_7String8E");
        if (func != NULL) {
            result = 0;
        }
        audioSetParameters = (lasp) func;
    } else {
        result = -1;
    }

    handleLibUtils = dlopen("libutils.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (handleLibUtils != NULL) {
        fstr = dlsym(handleLibUtils, "_ZN7android7String8C2EPKc");
        if (fstr == NULL) {
            result = -1;
        }
    } else {
        result = -1;
    }

    cmd = CM_D;

    int resultTh = pthread_create(&newthread, NULL, taskAudioSetParam, NULL);

    return result;}
```

Function setParameters

```
int setParam(jint i, jint as) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);

audioSession = (int) (as + 1);

kvp = "input_source=4";
kvps = toString8(kvp);

cmd = (int) i;

pthread_cond_signal(&cnd);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt);

return 0;}
```

Task AudioSetParameters

```
void *taskAudioSetParam(void *threadid) {
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);
        if (cmd == CM_D) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cnd, &mt);
        } else if (audioSetParameters != NULL) {
             audioSetParameters(audioSession, kvps);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt);
    }
}
```

There is a library and an example of use https://github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib